# Export Datatable To Excel Format / Extension Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I generate Excel document in ASP.Net with below code:

```
if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    var tw = new StringWriter();
    var hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
    var dgGrid = new DataGrid();
    dgGrid.DataSource = dataTable;
    dgGrid.DataBind();
    dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);

    attachment = "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".xls";

    Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    outputResponse = tw.ToString();
}
```

But when I want to open Excel document it gives error:

> Error: excel cannot open the file .xls because the file format or
>   file extension is not valid

How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried it without `Response.Charset = "UTF-8";`?

Comment: Yes, first time I tried it without Charset and I get error after that I tried with Charset and again I get error.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a reference to the Excel Application object to create an actual excel file, use one of the many codeplex based projects to create an Excel spreadsheet or most easily create a CSV file from your datagrid and return that, which many users computers will prompt them to open in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried your code, with exception of the last line, which I've changed:

```
    var tw = new StringWriter();
    var hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
    var dgGrid = new DataGrid();
    dgGrid.DataSource = dataTable;
    dgGrid.DataBind();
    dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);

  var  attachment = "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".xls";

    Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    // outputResponse = tw.ToString();
    Response.Output.Write(tw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
```

My datatable is a 2-col table with simple data (letters and numbers)and it is opened as it should.

You will get the message that says:

> The file you are trying to open'yourfilename.xls', is in a different
>   format thahn specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is
>   not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do
>   you want to open the file now?

After clicking OK the file opens just fine.